# Rails re-factor: How can I refactor this to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

These two lists are only slightly different as I need to treat the first 3 items a little differently than the rest. The only reason this isn't working now is because the variable with the regex is called twice. Any idea how to get the first 3 items (as shown in the first %li) separated from the rest without having to repeat everything like this?

```
%ul.list_container

  - @links.sort_by { |link| link.votes.where(:up => true).count - link.votes.where(:up => false).count }.reverse.first(3).each do |link|

  %li
    .various_containers
    %p
      = link_to link.title, "http://youtube.com/embed/#{link.url.to_s.match(/\/\/youtu.be\/(\S+)$/)[1]}/?rel=0", :class => "youtube title_link"
    = link.url_html


  - @links.sort_by { |link| link.votes.where(:up => true).count - link.votes.where(:up => false).count }.reverse.drop(3).each do |link|

  %li{:style => 'margin-bottom: 50px;'}
    .various_containers
    %p
    = link_to link.title,"http://youtube.com/embed/#{link.url.to_s.match(/\/\/youtu.be\/(\S+)$/)[1]}/?rel=0", :class => "youtube title_link"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the each_with_index method and customize each loop depending of the index value.

```
%ul.list_container
  - @links.sort_by { |link| link.votes.where(:up => true).count - link.votes.where(:up => false).count }.reverse.each_with_index do |link, index|
  %li{ :style => "#{index < 3 ? 'margin-bottom: 50px;' : ''}" }
    .various_containers
    %p= link_to link.title, "http://youtube.com/embed/#{link.url.to_s.match(/\/\/youtu.be\/(\S+)$/)[1]}/?rel=0", :class => "youtube title_link"
    - if index < 3
      = link.url_html
```

Comment: thanks! it seems like that should work but I'm still getting a no method error   (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) like I was getting when it was called twice.  It's coming from the regex, do you see any reason why that would cause that?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks Nicolas. It's all working now. My regex just didn't cover a particular format I had as a url. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A few things. You have a lot of code, including ActiveRecord lookups, in the view where it does not belong. By the time it gets to the view, `@links` should already be transmogrified into whatever simple collection you want to iterate over.

So the view should look like this:

```
-@prepared_links.each do |link, url_html|
  %p
    =link_to link.title, link.embedded_url, :class => "youtube title_link"
    =url_html
```

This means you need a few additional methods: `embedded_url` can go in your Link model and can essentially just be that `"http://youtube.com/embed/.../?rel=0"` string you have in `link_to` now.

As for displaying `url_html` for the first three, try something like this in your controller:

```
def my_method
  @prepared_links = Link.sorted_by_vote_count # you'll have to add this method as well
  url_htmls = @prepared_links[0..2].map(&:url_html)
  @prepared_links = @prepared_links.zip(url_htmls)
end
```

This will give you an array of prepared links as paired values, in which the first three will be `[some_link, url_html]`, and everything after the first three will be `[some_link, nil]`, meaning nothing will be displayed for `url_html` unless it's actually there.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great answer, I just need to digest it as it's a bit above my level right now. Cheers!

Comment: Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.